# Rotate pdf using wkhtmltopdf and php

Tags: php, rotation, wkhtmltopdf

How can I create a PDF document in A3 format that is rotated 90 degrees? I'm using wkhtmltopdf with php. I've tried to set variables for width and height but it doesn't work, and I can't find any function for rotating the document. Has anyone used wkhtmltopdf and rotated the pdf document?

Kind regards
H

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use wkhtmltopdf to set landscape orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16833528/use-wkhtmltopdf-to-set-landscape-orientation)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean orientation landscape? `$ wkhtmltopdf -O landscape`

If you are talking about rotating the page itself, see this question
[How rotate a pdf document using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403372/how-rotate-a-pdf-document-using-php)